# How to pass php array value to javascript variable

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have working on core php, i have getting all values from database(select query) in this i have to executed while loop and changed to array variable after i have to pass that array value to javascript variable how to pass this please help.

here my code:

```
<?php
include "db_connection.php";
$locations=array();
    $query =  $conn->query('SELECT `pg_address` FROM `tbl_master_property` limit 10');
     while ($row =$query->fetch_assoc()) {
       $list[] = $row;
    }
    $locations=$list;
    //echo "<pre>";print_r($locations);die;
    //echo "<pre>";print_r($cart_info_json);die;

?>  

<script type="text/javascript">
var geocoder;
var map;
var data = <?php echo json_encode($locations); ?>; 
//console.log(data);
alert(data);
```

in this alert is showing (object,object,object,object,object,object,object,object)

Comment: try `console.log(data);`

Comment: This is the expected behaviour of `alert` it's much like `echo` when it prints `Array` ie. it's meant for strings.

Comment: $list[] = $row; here array

Comment: you have to parse the JSON Object to show it in HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try :

```
alert(JSON.stringify(data));
```

but i would recommend `console.log(data);` and debug in the console.